# Laravel and Inertia.js does not delete record

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm actually struggling with removing the record, product from my custom managing product system. I've already built the URL but if I click on button, nothing happens, just console.log works well..

The HTML:

```
<tr v-for="product in products" :key="products.id">
   <td>{{product.id}}</td>
   <td>{{product.product_sku}}</td>
   <td>{{product.product_name}}</td>
   <td>{{product.stock_qty}}</td>

   <td>
      <button @click="editProduct(product)" class="btn btn-primary">
          Edit
      </button>
      <button @click="deleteProduct(product)" class="btn btn-danger">
          Delete
      </button>

  </td>
</tr>
```

And the web.php route:

```
Route::delete('/products/delete/{product}', [ProductController::class, 'destroy'])->name('products.destroy');
```

The JS code:

```
export default {
    props: ['products'],
    components: {
        AppLayout,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            editmode: false,  
        }
    },
    methods: {
        deleteProduct(products) {
            console.log(products.id);
            console.log('/admin/products/delete/' + products.id);
            this.$inertia.delete('/admin/products/delete/' + products.id);
        },                      
   }
```

}

I tried lot of combinations of solutions from stackoverflow and nothing working for me as well..
The console.log givings me onclick these results (for example):

```
    3
   /admin/products/delete/3
```

The ProductController.php destroy function:

```
public function destroy(Product $product): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
{
    $this->authorize('delete', Product::class);

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $this->productService->setModel($product)->destroy();

        DB::commit();

        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();

        Log::error($e->getMessage());

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

And the ProductServiceEloquent.php destroy function:

```
public function destroy()
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $this->repository->delete($this->getModel()->id);
        DB::commit();
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        DB::rollBack();

        throw new \Exception('Produkt nelze odstranit');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I just appreciate any help..

EDIT: Noticed an error: `local.ERROR: No query results for model [App\Models\Product]`. in storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: Hi @waterloomatt, sorry I didn(t attached more code, so I attached the productcontroller.php and productserviceeloquent.php functions :)

Comment: Sorry, still learning new patterns in laravel after few years.. I attached the error which I getting in laravel.log

Comment: The row exists in DB but if I try delete other IDs which are exists too it still giving me that error into laravel.log

Comment: @waterloomatt I've already tried to Log::info in service, repository, controller and it logs my custom message, so I don't have any idea where I can have something wrong..

Comment: OK, so move on to debugging something more useful like the request payload. Is the incoming ID what you expect? In your controller, is the `$product` model an instance or is it null? If it's a model instance does it make its way all the way through to the repository? What is `authorize` actually doing? Is that where it is failing? You need to do a lot more debugging to isolate _where_ that error message is coming from. Without anymore details we can't really help you and this question will be closed. I'm going to delete my comments to clean up this thread. Maybe do the same?

Comment: One last tip. Get rid of everything except the barebones to isolate the problem. So comment out `authorize` and your transactions. Add more useful logging such as `Log::info(request()->all())` or `Log::info($product)`. Do that in multiple places. Does `$this->getModel()` in your repo actually return a model? Does `$this->getModel()->id`  actually return an ID? You have nested transactions in the controller and repo. You can remove one set. Actually in this case you don't need them at all since you're only deleting from 1 table.